# Checking for palindromes using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, homework, palindrome

This is a homework assignment, but it's already done and it's not for a grade; it's meant as a refresher for the rest of the course. I've never done anything with dynamic memory allocation in C before, so I'm assuming I've done at least something wrong.

The goal is to write a program that takes a string from a user and checks to see if it's a palindrome. All non-letter characters are ignored, and dynamic memory allocation is required.

It works fine and I'm pretty happy with it, but I have no way of knowing if I've done things the "right" or "wrong" way. So, could anyone look over it really quickly and point out all the stupid things I've done?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    //str holds raw input
    //str_san holds sanitized input
    char *str = (char *)malloc(50), *str_san;
    //i and k are the index counters
    //len is the length of the sanatized string
    int i = 0, k = 0, len;

    //get a string from the user
    printf("Enter a message: \n");
    //store it in str
    scanf("%s", str);

    //make str_san as small as possible
    str_san = (char*)malloc(strlen(str) + 1);

    //copy only letters into the sanitized string
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') {
            str_san[k] = str[i] + 32; //changes uppercase to lowercase
            k++;
        }

        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') {
            str_san[k] = str[i];
            k++;
        }

        i++;
    }

    //str is no longer needed
    free(str);

    //terminate sanitized string
    str_san[k] = '\0';

    //set len to the length of str_san
    len = strlen(str_san);

    //check for palindrominess
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        //if the first letter does not equal the last letter then it's not a palindrome
        if (str_san[i] != str_san[len - i - 1]) {
            printf("Not a palindrome");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    //it is now safe to free str_san
    free(str_san);

    //if we've made it this far, it's a palindrome
    printf("Palindrome");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A reminder of the difference between C and C++: in C, you don't have to cast the return of `malloc`. Many C devs actually consider these casts to be both pointless and wrong (they hide errors, and are sometimes used to stomp out compiler warnings, which in turn causes bugs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should consider making this more modular (more functions).  It's not good to implement an entire program in `main()` as it could hurt readability.  While the separate comments are helpful, it's not a substitute for utilizing functions.

Essentially, you should just do the user-input and the function-calling in `main()`.  In general, try to have `main()` do as less as possible.  For instance, the string-copying and palindrome check should be done in separate functions, and `main()` should pass the strings to them at the calls.

```
void copyIntoString(char* str_san) {
    // ...
}
```

```
void checkForPalindromes(char* str_san) {
    // ...
}
```

The deallocation should still be done in `main()` since the allocation was done in there.  Also, the last output can be put into `checkForPalindromes()` since it's part of that functionality.

I also have some additional notes:

- If you need a separate variable like `len`, consider giving it a more accurate name so that it's known *which* length is being stored.  You have two strings, so the reader could easily forget which string to which it belongs.  Adding additional strings would then make it worse.
- Instead of using `printf()` for unformatted outputs:

  > ```
  > printf("Enter a message: \n");
  > ```

  use [`puts()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_puts.htm):

  ```
  puts("Enter a message: ");
  ```

  It also gives you a newline, so you can leave out yours (unless you want two).
- It's clearer to have each declaration or initialization done on a separate line, so instead of this:

  > ```
  > int i = 0, k = 0, len;
  > ```

  you should have this:

  ```
  int i = 0;
  int k = 0;
  int len;
  ```

  However, as the first two are loop counter variables, they should be placed right in front of the respective `for` loops (or *in* the `for` loops if you have C99 or above).  This will help with keeping close scope, which is good for readability and maintenance.
- This doesn't need to be a `while` loop:

  > ```
  > while (str[i] != '\0') {
  >     if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') {
  >         str_san[k] = str[i] + 32; //changes uppercase to lowercase
  >         k++;
  >     }
  >
  >     if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') {
  >         str_san[k] = str[i];
  >         k++;
  >     }
  >
  >     i++;
  > }
  > ```

  Since `i` is being incremented each time, it can just be a `for` loop:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') {
          str_san[k] = str[i] + 32; //changes uppercase to lowercase
          k++;
      }

      if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') {
          str_san[k] = str[i];
          k++;
      }
  }
  ```

  In addition, you can use [`isupper()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isupper.htm) instead of your own check:

  ```
  if (isupper(str[i])) {
  ```

  You can also use [`tolower()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_tolower.htm) to change a character to lowercase:

  ```
  str_san[k] = tolower(str[i]);
  ```

  The second `if` can then use [`islower()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_islower.htm):

  ```
  if (islower(str[i])) {
  ```

  Lastly, those two `if` can be consolidated into one.  This can be done by calling `tolower()` whenever *any* letter is encountered (the character will remain intact if it cannot be made lowercase).  Since all these operations only apply to letters, each character can first be checked with [`isalpha()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isalpha.htm).

  All of these function calls may add slight overhead, but if you don't care too much about efficiency or will mostly work with smaller strings, then it shouldn't matter.

  Taking each point into consideration, you should end up with this:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      if (isalpha(str[i])) {
          str_san[k] = tolower(str[i]);
          k++;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 5):

Overall, it's very good for a refresher. It's clear and easy to understand. In addition to what Jamal has said though, I have a few things to add.

---

You have to be very careful with `scanf` and `%s`. What happens if the user inputs something longer than 50 characters (well, really 49)? `scanf` will just keep on writing. As Loki Astari pointed out, this requires a single word (well, a single sequence of non-whitespace) to be incredibly long, but we typically shouldn't assume users are providing sane input.

In short, what I'm saying is that you have a potential buffer overflow. You need to either constrain the length of the input (`scanf("%49s", str)`), or use a different method of reading the input. If you stick to standard C, dynamic memory allocation is going to be involved in some kind of loop. If you break standard compliance, you can get away with a bit easier method.

If you're interested in standards compliance, you will want to look into `fgets`, and `realloc`. If you don't care being tied down to GNU C, see [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Dynamic-String-Input).

I would suggest that you go the standard compliant way and just put into a function so you only ever have to write it once. That way you don't have to needlessly break from the standard, but it remains easy to use.

---

```
//make str_san as small as possible
```

I'm being super picky now, but that's technically a lie. `strlen(str) + 1` is not guaranteed to be the shortest that `str_san` can be. A more accurate comment might mention that it's the shortest buffer that can be allocated without first counting how many elements are going to be copied into it.

---

The `while` loop for copying str into str_san is better fit (in my opinion) for a `for` loop.

---

I wouldn't reuse `len` but would instead have a second variable (`san_len` or something).

Comment: It would have to be a long word to be greater than 50 characters. :-) You may want to mention the `%s` stops at white space.

Comment: @LokiAstari Users are insane though :p. And good point about whitespace. Will edit.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty fine as a starter, but I feel there are some areas on we can focus:

1. Whenever we do know the size of data buffer predefined, it is prefer to use the `char` buffer rather than declaring a pointer and dynamically allocating.

   I prefer to use

   ```
   char str[50] = "";
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   char *str = (char *)malloc(50);
   ```
2. I feel it is a good practice to initialize the dynamically allocated memory.

   For example, after

   ```
   str_san = (char*)malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
   ```

   I would initialize the allocated memory as

   ```
   memset(str_san, 0, strlen(str) + 1);
   ```

   This will minimize your effort to set the last character to `NULL`.